# Batch file to copy files from one directory to another

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have two code bases of an application.  I need to copy all the files in all the directories with .java from the newer code base, to the older (so I can commit it to svn).

How can I write a batch files to do this?

Comment: Presumably you're talking about a Windows batch file, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

XCOPY /D ?

```
xcopy c:\olddir\*.java c:\newdir /D /E /Q /Y
```

Answer (score 1):

If you've lots of different instances of this problem to solve, I've had some success with [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) for this kind of copy/update/backup kind of thing.

There *is* a bit of a learning curve, though, and it *does* require you to have a Java runtime environment installed.

Answer (score 1):

I like [Robocopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy) ("Robust File Copy"). It is a command-line directory replication command. It was available as part of the Windows Resource Kit, and is introduced as a standard feature of Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008.